# Необязательные параметры запроса Spring

Tags: java, spring

Моя задача реализовать PATCH метод контроллера. 
Рассмотрим два случая:

- я хочу изменить поле field сущности на null. И тогда я передаю json:
  {"field":null}
- я не хочу изменять поле field. В json'е я опускаю поле field.

Spring в обоих случаях заполняет поле в DTO значением null, и сервис по изменению сущности не может различить две ситуации

В laravel (php) такое сделать легко - там данные из запроса сохраняются в ассоциативный массив. Можно проверить наличие того или иного поля в массиве.

Как быть в java?

Comment: required = false в java

Comment: Вариант предложенный@Санаев идеологически самый верный. Хотя для неподготовленного человека он выглядит как излишний boilerplate, однако он дает четкий контроль входных данных и катастрофически упрощает возможности автодокументирования API (например с помощью swagger)

Comment: К варианту, предложенному @Санаев можно добавить параметр аннотации `default` и чекать по нему. Например для `Int` задавать по умолчанию -1 и при таком значении не менять поле. Просто как пример. С другой стороны, что есть `null` как не удаление поля? Если у вас `null` и несуществующее поле являются разными ситуациями - это говорит об ошибке в архитектуре доменной области.

Comment: Десеривлизацию сделать легко если не передавать null значения, которые не должны передаваться по умолчанию.

Comment: Почему вы считаете, что null не должны передаваться, и что это ошибка архитектуры? Я не вижу тут противоречий

Comment: @rjhdby вариант, предложенный Санаевым, мне не подходит ещё и по той причине, что я ожидаю данные в теле запроса в json, поэтому аннотация RequestParam не годится

Comment: @Smartel никто не мешает аннотировать `@RequestBody` кастомную DTO-шку

Answer (score 1):

**Вот так попробуйте**

```
@//тип_запросаMapping
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<Ваш тип> method(@RequestParam(value = "parameter", required = false) Boolean parameter,
                @RequestParam(value = "id", required = false) Long id) {
```

Comment: В сущности, с которой я работаю, много полей (порядка 20). Будет ли правильно использовать эти поля как отдельные переменные? Тогда мне придётся в сервис-слой также передавать все эти 20 параметров. Неужели с помощью DTO нельзя описать проще?

Comment: можете с помощью дто

Comment: опишите подробнее, пожалуйста. Желательно простенький пример

Answer (score 0):

Проблему решил с помощью Optional. Обернутые в Optional поля могут быть представлены как null - если в запросе не было представлено это поле или Optional.empty - если поле передано как null явно

Comment: Однако, idea подсвечивает использование Optional в полях как нежелательное использование. Поиски продолжаются

Comment: не рекомендуется использовать опшионал в качестве параметров. даже не не рекомендуется, так делать нельзя!

Comment: как мне быть тогда?

Answer (score 0):

В данном случае у Spring нет точного решения. Можно в контроллере принимать объект в виде Map из полей и поочередно устанавливать значения полученных полей. Например:

```
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity partialUpdate(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Map<String, Object> fields) {
    YourEntity entity = findYourEntity(id);

    fields.forEach((fieldName, value) -> {
        Field field = ReflectionUtils.findField(KpiDataRecord.class, fieldName);
        ReflectionUtils.setField(field, entity, value);
    });

    saveObject(yourObject);

    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

В данным решении используется Reflection для установления значений полей нового объекта. Но в таком случае пропадает возможность удобной валидации получаемых объектов.